# file uploaded successfully but I can't find the file

Tags: php, file, azure, file-upload, filesystems

I'm using Azure server to open the website and linking to dropbox to store all the code files. I have an folder called 'image' but after uploading, though it shows "Uploaded!", I can't find that file.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if (isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){
        $location = 'image/';
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Uploaded!';            
        }else{
            echo 'There was an error.';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Plz choose a file.';
    }

}
?>
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Select file to upload:
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded file is in the `image` folder that is in the same folder of your `page.php`.

See your code:

```
$location = 'image/';
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
```

The final location of your file is `$location.$name`. This is `image/your_file_name.your_extension`

Comment: I know where my file is and I can see it through the URL, but I think it's in the folder called "image" on the Azure server, not in the dropbox folder called "image".  The question is I have no idea how to see the file list in the Azure folder.

Comment: It shows "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."